# Problem with left alignment in Calibre/iBooks

Tags: epub, calibre, css, apple-books, mac-os

Using Calibre I have tried to use ´text-align: left´ in CSS but viewing the resulting epub-file with iBooks the result is still justified text. How can I change to left alignment?[image]

Comment: Do you have "Justify text" turned on in iBooks -> Preferences -> General? That will override the CSS settings.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think text-align left and Justify text have anything to do with one another. Justification is usually controlled by the reading system, while text-align left is the default behavior for text. The css property text-align mainly has to do with alignment inside of a box (usually a single line). You could use another css property to scoot the text to the left or the right (margin, etc).

Comment: `text-align` does indeed distinguish `left` and `justify` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)). It is more likely a default setting is overriding this directive. More specificity ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)) may override the default setting, would need to test.